Некорректно сокращает строчки текста


* {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}   
.rpl {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-width: 70vw;
    max-height: 70vh;
}

.input {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgb(107, 107, 107, 7%);
}
.input > *:not(:last-child) {margin-right: 10px}
.input > svg { width: 20px; fill: #6a6a6a}
.input button {margin: -5px -10px -5px 0}
.btn {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: var(--b_c);
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: var(--fon);
}
textarea, input, select {flex: 1}
select, textarea, button, input {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 0;
    background: none;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
<div class="rpl">
    <div class="input">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36"><path d="M2.52 29.48c-3.36-3.36-3.36-8.82 0-12.18l6.69-6.74c3.31-3.31 8.81-3.31 12.12 0 2.97 2.97 3.42 7.72.97 11.152l-.06.09a1.9 1.9 0 0 1-2.65.44 1.9 1.9 0 0 1-.44-2.65l.06-.09a4.8 4.8 0 0 0-.51-6.19 4.81 4.81 0 0 0-6.79 0l-6.68 6.69c-1.87 1.82-1.87 4.91 0 6.79a4.79 4.79 0 0 0 6.18.51l.09-.12c.85-.56 2.04-.36 2.65.49.61.85.41 2.05-.44 2.66l-.09.06c-3.48 2.44-8.12 2.05-11.09-.91Z" style="opacity: .5"></path><path d="M33.47 6.51c3.36 3.36 3.36 8.82 0 12.18l-6.69 6.69a8.61 8.61 0 0 1-12.18 0 8.61 8.61 0 0 1-.91-11.09l.06-.09c.56-.85 1.75-1.05 2.65-.44.85.56 1.06 1.75.44 2.65l-.06.09c-1.36 1.85-1.15 4.52.51 6.19a4.81 4.81 0 0 0 6.79 0l6.68-6.69c1.87-1.87 1.87-4.96 0-6.79a4.79 4.79 0 0 0-6.18-.51l-.09.06c-.85.61-2.04.36-2.65-.44a1.9 1.9 0 0 1 .44-2.65l.09-.06a8.61 8.61 0 0 1 11.09.91z"></path></svg>
        <input name="title" value="Текс текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст" type="text" id="copy" disabled="">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">Копировать</button>
    </div>
</div>



На всех элементах присвоено свойство
letter-spacing: 1px;

Так как буквы, цифры слишком плотно друг к другу.
Из-за данного свойства, некорректно сокращает текст в моментах где сокращения не должно быть.
Как это поправить,,?
